# MediaController is not anchored with VideoView, it is displaying behind Videoview from lollipop in dialog,?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, mediacontroller

Not able to display MediaController in dialog from lollipop version.

**Code is showing MediaController below lollipop but not from lollipop.**

```
private void showMediacontroller(){

  View view =getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_viedo_dialog,null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(view);
  AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    videoview = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    final MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoview);
    // Set MediaController for VideoView
    videoview.setMediaController(mediaController);

    Log.i("Play", "is showing-->"+mediaController.isShowing());

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sample);
    videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoview.requestFocus();

    alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            videoview.start();
            mediaController.show();
            Log.i("Play", "is showing-->"+mediaController.isShowing());
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally i solved the issue which is mediacontroller showing behind the videoview ?**

> I took framelayout below videoview and anchor Mediacontroller with
>    framelayout.

Comment: If you could add that code, then that will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

public class AudioRecorderActivity extends BaseActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "AudioRecorderActivity";
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
private int mScreenDensity;
private MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager;
private static final int DISPLAY_WIDTH = 720;
private static final int DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 1280;
private MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
private VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;
private MediaProjectionCallback mMediaProjectionCallback;
private ToggleButton mToggleButton;
private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 10;

static {
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
    ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_audio_recording);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    mScreenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;

    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService
            (Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);

    mToggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle);
    mToggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) + ContextCompat
                    .checkSelfPermission(this,
                            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                        (this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ||
                        ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                                (this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
                    mToggleButton.setChecked(false);
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), R.string.label_permissions,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE",
                            new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                                            new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                                    .WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                                            REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
                                }
                            }).show();
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                    .WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                            REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
                }
            } else {
                onToggleScreenShare(v);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode != REQUEST_CODE) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unknown request code: " + requestCode);
        return;
    }
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                " Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mToggleButton.setChecked(false);
        return;
    }
    mMediaProjectionCallback = new MediaProjectionCallback();
    mMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
    mMediaProjection.registerCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback, null);
    mVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
    mMediaRecorder.start();
}

public void onToggleScreenShare(View view) {
    if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked()) {
        initRecorder();
        shareScreen();
    } else {
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();
        Log.v(TAG, "Stopping Recording");
        stopScreenSharing();
    }
}

private void shareScreen() {
    if (mMediaProjection == null) {
        startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);
        return;
    }
    mVirtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
    mMediaRecorder.start();
}

private VirtualDisplay createVirtualDisplay() {
    return mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("AudioRecorderActivity",
            DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT, mScreenDensity,
            DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
            mMediaRecorder.getSurface(), null /*Callbacks*/, null
            /*Handler*/);
}

private void initRecorder() {
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment
                        .DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/video.mp4");
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation + 90);
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class MediaProjectionCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if (mToggleButton.isChecked()) {
            mToggleButton.setChecked(false);
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
            Log.v(TAG, "Recording Stopped");
        }
        mMediaProjection = null;
        stopScreenSharing();
    }
}

private void stopScreenSharing() {
    if (mVirtualDisplay == null) {
        return;
    }
    mVirtualDisplay.release();
    //mMediaRecorder.release(); //If used: mMediaRecorder object cannot
    // be reused again
    destroyMediaProjection();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    destroyMediaProjection();
}

private void destroyMediaProjection() {
    if (mMediaProjection != null) {
        mMediaProjection.unregisterCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback);
        mMediaProjection.stop();
        mMediaProjection = null;
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "MediaProjection Stopped");
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[],
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_PERMISSIONS: {
            if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] +
                    grantResults[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                onToggleScreenShare(mToggleButton);
            } else {
                mToggleButton.setChecked(false);
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), R.string.label_permissions,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE",
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

}